# Upload file to box via netsuite Suitelet script

Tags: netsuite

I am having issue in uploading file to box Via NetSUite Suitelet.
I am able to connect through Postman. But I am not able to connect through NetSuite Suitelet. The call doesn't reach to Box at all.
Can someone please assist?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code you are trying?

Comment: var headers = {'Authorization': "Bearer " + 'hjhjhjhjhjjj'};
  var url = "https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content"; 
 var f = nlapiLoadFile('test/Capture001.png');
   var parent =
         {
          'id': '123'
         };
  var attribs = {
    'name' : 'Capture001.png',
    'parent' : parent
    };
  var body = {
    'attributes' : attribs,
    'file' : f.getName()
  };
  nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Json', JSON.stringify(body));

  var resp = nlapiRequestURL(url, JSON.stringify(body), headers, 'POST');
Response is blank 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I see an issue with, on the NetSuite side, is that you are missing a value in the call.  Where I still use that 1.0 function I call it like this:

```
nlapiRequestURL(url,JSON.stringify(body),headers,null,'POST');
```

The API calls for the following parameters:

```
nlapiRequestURL(url, postdata, headers, callback, httpMethod)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I have used this before and it doesn't work call back is only required for client script.

Comment: True.  But, that is the only thing I see that could be an issue.  Unless Box is just not replying at all?  Have you tried calling it with another client?  MAybe something like ARC?

Comment: Hi Mate 
I have tried the box file upload through postman and it is working fine. The issue only occurs when API is called through NetSuite. Do you have any other alternative available?